# What's the largest gauge THHN conductor I can add three of to an existing 1/2" EMT with 2#10 in it already?

Tags: subpanel

## Background

I am planning to upgrade my garage by adding a sub panel to it. Currently two circuits' wiring comes out of my main panel in my bsmt, via about 2 feet of 1/2" EMT *in* to a disconnect on the vinyl siding. The circuits are:

- 30A (2#10) for the air conditioning compressor
- 20A (2#12) for the garage

Coming *out* of the disconnect is 3/4" EMT which carries the 2#12 about 30 feet, 18 inches underground, to the garage.

### What I need help with...

I'd like to plan ahead so I'm curious to know what size wire I can upgrade the 2#12 to, *without* having to trench my backyard and upgrade the EMT. I've read the conduit fill capacity charts but it seems like the numbers are all for the same AWG.

***NOTE: This is my first post on this site, so if I'm missing any info just let me know.***

[image]

Comment: A 10/2 and 12/2 Romex cable will not fit in 1/2” EMT.  Do you mean THHN individual wires?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am probably using the wrong wording. Yes, THHN individual wires. No Romex, which is probably what I said mistakenly by using the gauge/quantity notation.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what the largest feeder is that I can run through 1/2" EMT, through the disconnect, and through the 3/4" EMT. Taking into consideration the 2#10 that is already in the 1/2" EMT between main panel and outdoor disconnect.

Comment: What is the load?

Comment: Great question. Not sure what it will get to, but right now it's garage lights, outlets, door opener, and 20A heat pump. hope that's what you meant!

Comment: Well I figured you meant EV, since that's the load *everybody's* trying to run in a garage these days. And hey, it increases your home's resale value to have a large 240V circuit ready for level 2 charging.  Not that the buyer has an EV, but the spouse is thinking about it, and it's a few dollars on the mortgage vs potentially thousands to hire the work done.  You know that a 2-wire feed can only support 240V loads right? You can't make 120V out of 2 hots and a conduit shell.  Possible with a transformer, but you need a quality one not a Chinese one off Amazon.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yeah, the plan in my head is to run two hots and a neutral all 6 AWG to a 6space-12circuit 100A subpanel in my garage, then use 4spaces for the two 240V EV circuits and then have a tandem use another space with 2 120V @ 20A breakers, and have 1space/2circuits leftover for expansion.

Comment: 3x#6 in 1/2" conduit won't work due to conduit fill. Since that is doomed and you have to lay new conduit anyway, you can break free of the high cost of copper and run #2 aluminum (in at least 1" pipe).  The #2 *with the conduit* will be cheaper than the #6. And will carry 90A instead of 65A if alone. Any dual-EV configuration should always use "Share2" power sharing tech, which pools their current allocations so one car can get all 60A if the other car isn't using it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica ah crap, sorry, I didn't specify that I am going to upgrade the short span of 1/2" with 3/4" from the panel to the disconnect, then use the existing buried 3/4" EMT.

Comment: How long is the conduit between the panel and this disconnect? The answer I'm fishing for is "less than 24 inches".

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Less than two feet!

Project just took a turn though! I realized I don't have 3/4"EMT buried in backyard, but 1/2" RMC instead! Going to keep it super simple since I am juggling a ton with new house, and run another 2#12 circuit to the garage's new heat pump. Thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: I really hate to break this to you, but you can only have 1 circuit per voltage to a (detached) outbuilding. So one 120 and one 240 is all you get.  I had a feeling it would be RMC since EMT would rust very quickly.  Still, 3x#8 does fit in 1/2". You would need to enlarge the short conduit into the house to also have 2x#10.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Wow, the code is tight, but for good reasons I truly believe. Got an electrician's number yesterday so I'm going to give him a call and see if he can do the whole kitten kaboodle...trench the backyard and put the biggest subpanel I can in the garage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ed Beal's answer is correct but doesn't (I think) answer the specific question of: 10 AWG x 2 + *what else* in a 1/2" EMT. In this particular case, I think you would likely want to replace the 12 AWG x 2 with 'n' x 3 - that way you can have a proper 240V/120V subpanel (2 hots + neutral). In any case, EMT takes care of the ground, as you have already done.

Using [Southwire's Conduit Fill Calculator](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-conduit), if I add the 10 AWG x 2 and another 10 AWG x 3, everything is OK. Go up to 10 AWG x 2 + 8 AWG x 3 and no good (48.58%).

Your 3/4" EMT can handle up to 6 AWG x 3. So if you need more than 10 AWG can provide (30A @ 75 C) then if you replace the 1/2" EMT with 3/4" EMT you can use 6 AWG x 3 to the garage and have room for the 10 AWG x 2 as well. 6 AWG will get you 65A at 75 C.

Answer (score 2):

For an upgrade you can have 6#10 thhn in 1/2”.  If I understand your question correctly. Or pull everything and put 3 #8 for the sub use the conduit for the ground and there is 4 wire 50 amp sub.

Comment: I added a picture if it helps.

Comment: You can remove the disconnect and install a small nema 3R breaker panel, I have a very similar setup on my home. 2 double pole breakers with lockouts and a single pole going going to the 120v GFCI service outlet that has a heavy duty cover or “in use cover”  I only have 5 spaces but you can get more over 8 is usually a waste for outside panels but not always.

Comment: This is sort of an extra question, sorry, but is my 3/4" fill capacity (that runs from the disconnect to the garage) limited to what the 1/2" (that runs from main panel two feet up to the disconnect) can carry?

Comment: I'm just curious if I need to remove the drywall and upgrade the short run of 1/2" EMT to 3/4" or more.

Comment: If you upsize you can put larger wires in 1/2” will allow 6 conductors if it is a short pull with only a couple of 90’s I would keep what you have, but yes you can always put in a larger pipe (conduit).

Comment: @RudyOnRails you'd only need to remove enough drywall to get the larger conduit through the hole. It's possible that the hole in the drywall is already big enough for a larger pipe and that the larger hole is hidden behind whatever the conduit is entering. In either case, if you need to make a bigger hole, do so. If it's not a pretty hole, there should be a box or something that will hide the rough edges.

Comment: @FreeMan ahh i think i see what you mean. I thought I would have to expose above the panel by removing the drywall but you're saying maybe i can just loosen the nuts and slide out the 1/2" and put in the 3/4" since the disconnect sits directly above the indoor panel.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the charts, use a conduit fill *calculator*. They are online.   Or you can do it with plain old geometry.

The two #10 wires can share 1/2” EMT with two #8 wires.  The #10 will be limited to 32 amps and the #8 will be limited to 44 amps.

### 120V loads, option 1: not pretty

However, noting that the #12 has a white wire, you seem to have 120V loads in the garage.  44A of 120V is practically useless, the only thing I can see you do with that is have a small subpanel where you split it into a TT30 for a travel trailer, and a 20A circuit for normal garage loads.  Now if your goal is EV charging, this will suck. EVSE's aren't really expecting 30A@120V, and it will be slow.

[image]

### 120V loads option 2: dedicated 30A line

In this case we leave the #10 wire alone, leave the #12 wire for the mandatory garage circuit (the rationale for 20A is EV charging, nice job thinking that through, NFPA!)

And we add the largest circuit we can.  That is #10 wire giving 30A nominal @240V.
The reason you can't get #8 is it won't quite fit, as will become apparent.

### Option 3: Let's throw out the Code (but not the reasons)

Code says the point of the 20A garage circuit is EV charging. We have that covered, so let's downgrade it to #14/15A.  Mind you Code does not give permission to do this!

Replace the #10 with solid and use solid #14.

Now we have *a little* more room in the conduit, and can run #8 wire for the EV circuit. Almost. If no one busts your chops over 0.46 percent.

[image]

Comment: Except that as clearly shown in the picture, the existing 10 AWG are stranded. So the actual fill (unless you replace the 2' of 10 Stranded with 10 Solid) is 42.23%. All arguably just fine for 2 feet, but slightly more of a technical violation. Of course, I still like "replace the 1/2" with 3/4" and use 6 AWG and a subpanel" solution.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact good catch.  Fixed.  I agree with changing to three #6 and putting subpanels both at the A/C and the garage.

Comment: But 3 x 6 AWG gets you to 48% fill on the 1/2". So if you replace the short conduit with 3/4" then you can have 3 x 6 AWG **and** 2 x 10 AWG, which saves having to put in a subpanel at the A/C, only adding one at the garage (where you really need it).

Comment: @manassehkatz I meant in your context of 3/4" conduit. My thinking is at 3/4" why stop there, go to 1" and run #4 or #2AL from the main. Then 4-space sub for the A/C, then 3x#8 for a full 50A 120/240V delivered to the garage. This sidesteps the annoying derates for multiple circuits, which really bite #8